# Google Charts mysql PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts

Trying to get Google charts to load data from local mysql database via php. Page shows up blank.  Based off this [example code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?hl=en). Any idea how to fix?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
    'modules':[{
        'name':'visualization',
        'version':'1',
        'packages':['corechart']
    }]
}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Time', 'Temperature'],
            <?php
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "TempDB2");
                $query = "SELECT * FROM TempMeas";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                mysqli_close($con);

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $time = $row['MeasTime'];
                    $temp = $row['Temp'];
                    echo "['$time', $temp],";
                }
            ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            curveType: 'function',
            legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think calling `mysqli_close()` before fetching might be closing the connection is needed for `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: Thanks tried that but still blank.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: The javascript part is running fine so the problem is the php. I would see what `var_dump($con)` and `var_dump($result`) return

Comment: Tried putting it in like this and a few other ways but nothing outputs, still blank page.  Did I put it in correctly?  <?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "TempDB2");
 
 $query = "SELECT * FROM TempMeas";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
 var_dump($con);
 var_dump($result);
 mysqli_close($con);

Comment: yeah that looks good but if you are still running your php code inside script tags it might be the case that the php debug output or errors will be visible only in the page's source code. Also try and replace `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "TempDB2");` with `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "TempDB2") or die(mysqli_error());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent the last couple of days messing around with this and I've found the best solution is to de-couple the MySQL queries from the charts part and read it from a JSON file or php page as per https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example#getdataphp-file

This way you can start with a static JSON file and ensure your chart is displaying correctly. Once this works then recreate the same JSON file using PHP and MySQL queries.

```
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "jsonData.php",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

Making sure your JSON is correct is paramount. It looks like you are pulling in a DATETIME which means that if this is not formatted correctly then your graph won't display. It needs to be "Date(2016,05,26,04,10)"

[JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) is your friend.